# Создание древовидного inventory в ansible tower

Tags: ansible, автоматизация, devops

Приветствую!
Пробую перейти на ansible tower, но возникла проблема при адаптации одного из инвентори файлов. 
Как правильно сделать подобную структуру в товере?

Когда много хостов удобно разбить переменные по группам, а глобально использовать region
    stage (inventory file)

```
#[kafka]
#dev-kafka-01   ansible_host=8.8.8.8


[kibana]
dev-kibana-01   ansible_host=8.8.8.8

[elasticsearch]
dev-elastic-01   ansible_host=8.8.8.8

[logstash]
dev-logstash-01   ansible_host=8.8.8.8

##################################
#             VARS               #
##################################

[region:vars]
region_name=stage
ansible_user=user
ansible_ssh_port= 22
ansible_connection= ssh
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=



##################################
##          childhood           ##
##################################

[region:children]
frontend
backend
database

    [frontend:children]
    kibana

    [backend:children]
    logstash

    [database:children]
 #   kafka
    elasticsearch
```

Сделал для товера плейбук без include, чтобы наверняка

```
elk_tower.yml (playbook)
---
- hosts: elasticsearch
  become: True
  roles:
    - common
    - oracle-java
#    - cerebro
    - elasticsearch

- hosts: logstash
  become: True
  roles:
    - logstash

- hosts: kibana
  become: True
  roles:
    - nginx
    - kibana
...
```

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 2):

Может кому пригодится, помогла программа для импорта inventory файла.
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/tower-manage.html#inventory-import

```
awx-manage inventory_import --source=stage --inventory-name=destination_name [--inventory-id=]
```

Что помогло понять принцип. 
Группы в группах я создал правильно, но в названиях хостов в этих группах нужно было писать не ip адрес, а dev-elastic-01 и в переменных самого хоста уже указывать:
    region_name: stage
    ansible_host: 8.8.8.8